# How to set each individual bar in a bar chat to a different color in ReportLab?

Tags: python, python-2.7, reportlab

I am using this function to create a bar chart using [Reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/)

```
def make_drawing():
    from reportlab.lib import colors
    from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing
    from reportlab.graphics.charts.barcharts import HorizontalBarChart
    drawing = Drawing(400, 200)


    data = [
           (13, 5, 20, 22, 37, 98, 19, 4),
           ]

    names = ["Cat %s" % i for i in xrange(1, len(data[0])+1)]

    bc = HorizontalBarChart()
    bc.x = 20
    bc.y = 50
    bc.height = 200
    bc.width = 400
    bc.data = data
    bc.strokeColor = colors.white
    bc.valueAxis.valueMin = 0
    bc.valueAxis.valueMax = 100
    bc.valueAxis.valueStep = 10
    bc.categoryAxis.labels.boxAnchor = 'ne'
    bc.categoryAxis.labels.dx = -10
    bc.categoryAxis.labels.fontName = 'Helvetica'
    bc.categoryAxis.categoryNames = names

    drawing.add(bc)
    return drawing
```

By default the bar chart color is set to red

[image]

I add these two lines after setting bc.categoryAxis.categoryNames

```
    bc.bars[0].fillColor = colors.blue
    bc.bars[1].fillColor = colors.red
```

In the hope to set the first bar to color blue. However all the bars are now in color blue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bars charts can have multiple bars at each position like this

[image]

So, bars is 2 dimensional array. You can set color to individual bars like this

```
bc.bars[(0, 0)].fillColor = colors.blue
bc.bars[(0, 1)].fillColor = colors.green
```

which will generate chart like this

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's a late answer but this was the first result I found when looking for the same solution.

Yes if you have a series of bars in one bar chart you color each series by its index. But to color each bar in one series you use the coordinates:

```
bc.bars[(0, 1)].fillColor = colors.blue
bc.bars[(0, 2)].fillColor = colors.red
```

etc.

http://reportlab-users.reportlab.narkive.com/CZRXnJBQ/can-we-change-the-color-of-each-bar-in-a-vertical-bar-chart#post3